# Flutter and Dart installed in Android Studio and the App builds, yet it is janky and Flutter Doctor says it isn't installed

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

So, the App builds, I can test the App and *most* things work as they should, until I wanted to try to make a stream:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class OptimizationsPageBloc {
  final _optimizationController = BehaviorSubject<List<Optimization>>();
  final _feedbackController = BehaviorSubject<bool>();

  Stream<List<Optimization>> get optimizations => _optimizationController.stream;

  void dispose() {
    _optimizationController.close();
  }
}
```

`The method 'BehaviorSubject' isn't defined for the type 'OptimizationsPageBloc'.`

Googling the error message, restarts, nothing helped. alt-enter only suggests to create this class and no imports. So I am all out of ideas as I literally copied another class in from another project but no where in my new Project does it work (Stream, by the way, works, it just sees _optimizationController as a dynamic)

Flutter Doctor for Android Studio says:

```
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
```

But the App builds, so I very much doubt they aren't installed. I also made 4 different Pages up until now and they all work perfectly - just the BehaviorSubject (and other Subjects) are the ones who started being weird. ESPECIALLY because they work in another Project perfectly fine, also another weird thing is that the other project has files and folders, while in this new Project I can only make new directories and not manually put new directories into empty directories (as I sad above, it's janky).

Also in the Project view it says

`>second_project[secondproject] ~/repos/flutter/second_project`

but in the working project it is

`>first_project ~/repos/flutter/first_project`

What is happening here? This is all the oddities I could collect right now, if you need me to add any more info, tell me!

Comment: Try cleaning your project and restart your IDE. I had this issue once on VSCode and needed to reinstall the Flutter and Dart plugins for it to work again.

Comment: @AdityaNigam I will try that, thank you!

Comment: @AdityaNigam reinstall, restart, nothing works. I fixed the problem but that only by letting someone else creating and pushing the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common issue that comes with Flutter 1.22.2. You can try the beta channel release for Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

I technically didn't fix it but there was obviously something wrong on my end, when my collegue created and pushed the project for me suddenly everything worked, all I needed then is to add all the files and everything manually back. Still weird and I'll have the same issue again for the next project